# MVS 2015 VC++ output is blank

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I went to run my first program in MVS 2015 in VC++ and the output window that opens is blank.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Test!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}


1>------ Build started: Project: Test1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Test 1.cpp
1>  Test1.vcxproj -> c:\users\shuey\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Test1\Debug\Test1.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Then I get a blank cmd window

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running your program by opening cmd and then executing it there?

Comment: Control +F5 is the keyboard shortcut for  Start without debugging  this is how I have been starting my program so no change. If I have cmd open when I run the program it just opens a new cmd window over it.

Comment: @Thunderchief *If I have cmd open when I run the program it just opens a new cmd window over it* -- Did you go to the command prompt, type in the name of the executable, and press enter?  I need to ask this, since your description sounds like you just opened a cmd window and "ran the program" from explorer or something similar.

Comment: I am running the program from the IDE. am I missing a step I'm not aware of?  When I go to the command prompt and type in the executable and press enter I get " is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." .

Comment: We've been getting these questions all week.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem!!